# Finetune Text embeddings using BERT?

Tags: nlp, embedding

are the text emebddings also fine-tuned when fine-tuning for classification task? Or up to which layer are the encodings fine-tuned (sencond last layer)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using [the original BERT repository](https://github.com/google-research/bert) published by Google, all layers are trainable; meaning: no freezing at all. You can check that by printing `tf.trainable_variables()`.

Comment: Is this also for fine tuning the case ? I want the encodings fine tuned in my data.

Comment: Yes. Everything is going to be fine-tuned with your data.